# upper-bound of a Volterra-type integral?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, delay-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto [0,+\infty)$ be a normalized (i.e. integral is 1) delay kernel, $t>0$, and $y\in\mathbb{R}$ is a solution (unknown) of a differential equation. I want to find an upper bound (supremum) of the integral
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}|y(t-u)|f(u)du.
$$
In particular, what I really want is to have
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}|y(t-u)|f(u)du \leq |y(t)|.
$$
Can this inequality be justified? Under what conditions?

Comment: This is only correct if $|y|$ is non-decreasing. But it cannot be true in general. Consider $y(t) = 1 + \sin t$ at $t = (2k+1)\pi$. Then $y(t) = 0$ but the left hand side is positive.

Comment: If $t=(2k+1)\pi$, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then I'm thinking that $y(t)=1\neq 0$ in your example. Am I missing something here? - unless if you meant to write $y(t)=1+\cos(t)$.

Comment: Sorry, $y(t) = 1 + \cos t$ of course. You can take $y$ to be any bounded non-negative function $\ne 0$ but with zeroes somewhere, and the inequality fails at these zeroes.

Comment: Given a differential equation whose unknown solution is denoted by $y(t)$, how would you go about proving that $|y(t)|$ is non-decreasing for all $t$, without explicitly solving the equation. What would be the best strategy to adopt?

Comment: (a) Show that the sign of $y(t)$ does not change (for starters). (b) Find an integral representation of $y(t)$ or better of $y'(t)$. (c) Find a differential inequality for $y'$ that proves that it cannot become negative. (d) Show that $y'(t)$ has a non-negative limit. Or some combination of arguments like these.

Comment: Upon further reflection, $y(t)$ cannot be non-decreasing for all $t$. The reason for this is because I'm trying to establish asymptotic stability. In other words, I'm trying to establish that $y(t)\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Adopting a Lyapunov functional approach, I end up with the following upper right Dini derivative: $$D^{+}V(t)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\xi_k\left\{-|y_k(t)|+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}c_j|a_{kj}||y_j(t)|+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}c_j\left(|a_{jk}|+|a_{kj}|\right)\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}|y_j(t-s)|f_{kj}(s)ds\right\}.$$ The $f_{kj}$ are still delay kernels as defined above. The $\xi_k$, $c_j$, and $a_{kj}$ are all positive real parameters. The unknown $y_j(t)$ has the same interpretation as above. What's the best approach to show that $D^{+}V(t)$ is strictly negative? This is the crux of the problem, really.

Comment: I've read about Razumikhin-type theorems, but I'm not sure how they may be employed in a problem such as this one.

Comment: You should post this as a new question, including the equation(s) that $y$ satisfies.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted a new question as per your suggestion.